# Unable to start PostgreSQL in macOS. Getting “Role ‘apple’ does not exist.”

Tags: macos, postgresql

No matter what command I am trying, I always get this error:

```
 role "apple" does not exist
```

I tried following commands:

```
psql
createdb -s postgres
```

And it gives me same error. Consider `apple` is my username of computer.

And then I tried

```
sudo -su postgres
```

And it gave me error

```
sudo: unknown user: postgres
```

I had installed using :

```
brew install postgres@9.5
```

And this is the only version I have.

Comment: How did you install Postgres?

Comment: brew install postgres@9.5, and I have 9.5 only and I added the bin directory of that to PATH

Comment: If you installed through Homebrew, consider filing a bug report: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues – make sure to include all the required info.